# Getting the time and date now in 16 bits hexadecimal (16 characters)

Tags: java, date, time, epoch

I'm currently using

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()/1000
```

to get the result of today's time in the calendar in seconds. I need to output the result into something like this:

```
0000000ED76420A5
```

Big or little endian doesn't matter, but I've not knowledgeable enough to be able to convert it, my friend told me it has something to do with Epoch time, but I'm unsure why I don't get the correct date time when I convert.

I'm using an offset of: 62168515200 but I too do not understand what those mean.

I would appreciate any help or resources.. thanks.

edit: I'm using an epoch time converter online (1574669899 as of now), but with this number, how can I get a date-time in Java? If I'm able to get a proper date-time in Java, I might be able to do the conversion, right?

Comment: get the epoch -> turn that into a hex representation -> send it somewhere... on the other side, for de-serializing: turn the hex into long -> get the date from that epoch...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツthanks, but how do i calculate the epoch? what do i need? current datetime in seconds... what else? thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the cumbersome old legacy date API `Calendar` instead of the modern date time API?

Comment: can you use java 8???

Answer (score 4):

If you have Java 8, then use `java.time` and some `static` methods of `Long` in order to get an instant in epoch millis, convert it to a hexadecimal representation and do it the other way round. Finally, the following example shows how to create a date time and print it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // take the instant in epoch milliseconds
    long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    // print them once
    System.out.println("millis:\t\t\t" + millis);
    // convert them to a hexadecimal representation
    String hexMillis = Long.toHexString(millis);
    // print them
    System.out.println("Hex-Millis:\t\t" + hexMillis);
    // convert the millis back, THIS NEEDS A LEADING 0x
    long convertedMillis = Long.decode("0x" + hexMillis);
    // print the value and see that it's the same as above
    System.out.println("Converted millis:\t" + convertedMillis);
    // create an Instant from the converted millis
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(convertedMillis);
    // create a LocalDateTime from the Instant using the system default time zone
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    // print the date-time formatted
    System.out.println("LocalDateTime:\t\t" 
            + localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
}
```

On my system, this outputs

```
Hex-Millis:         16ea1bbd03c
Converted millis:   1574671470652
LocalDateTime:      2019-11-25T09:44:30.652
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure, will it not work for earlier Java versions? :)

Comment: java.time has been backported to Java 6 and 7, so it will work there. See https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

Comment: @Ken for Java 6 and 7, see the comment by @OleVV, for antique versions you need to rely on `java.util`...

Comment: For **Java 8 and later**, *java.time* is built-in, ditto for **Android 26+**. For **Java 6 & 7**, see the [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). For **Android before 26**, use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), a wrapper around that Java backport. For **Java 5**, use [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) version 2, the predecessor to *java.time*. For **Java 4**, use Joda-Time version 1.

Answer (score 3):

For truncation on seconds as asked:

```
    long t = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();
    String s = String.format("%016X", t);
    System.out.println(s);
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(t);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);

000000005DDB955A
2019-11-25T09:48:26+01:00[Europe/Maastricht]
```

For the old class Date, Calendar:

```
long t = new Date().getTime(); // ms
```

The format %16x for no leading 0s, and a-f instead of A-F.

Of course storing also the ms and even ns makes sense. See the solution of @deHaar

Comment: Most of the examples I've seen are all similar to yours, they all start with lots of zeros and then hexadecimals in a 16-bit format. I was wondering what are the differences between deHaar 's solution and yours? Is @deHaar's solution based on later Java versions?

Comment: @deHaar just uses a better precision (not just seconds), and drops the many preceding zeroes.  We both use the new java time classes, `Date` and `Calendar` being the old way. One could consider for international usage a time independent of the time zone, `ZoneId.of("Z")` or `"UTC"`. I gave an answer too, only because a factor 1000 for s/ms gives different values.